# Ubuntu boots to black screen, cannot access Grub

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia

I have just installed Ubuntu on my new machine - a Skylake build with an NVidia 900 series GPU. As such I have a problem in that Ubuntu (and the install USB stick I used) both boot to a black screen.

I could easily set the nomodeset flag for the USB stick installer to get that to work, but I can't do the same for booting the now installed Ubuntu as no matter when or how I press shift, Grub does not want to show up - instead I get a solid purple screen for a few seconds and then the screen goes black.

Are there any other ways of setting nomodeset, or any other suggestions for how to boot Ubuntu or get into Grub?

For extra information, I installed Ubuntu with the LVM option.

Edit: I have looked at other answers on here and elsewhere, but all assume you can eventually get into Grub as far as I could find.

Edit 2: the proposed question this is a duplicate of only proposes solutions which involve access to Grub (which I do not for unknown reasons), unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: when you see Grub (of your isntalled Ubuntu or pendrive) press `E` button on your keyboard, then goto the end of second last line and type this `nomodeset nouveau.modeset=0` and press `Ctrl + X` and boot, then tell me if you get black screen or not

Comment: Did you install in UEFI mode, then use escape key (perhaps several times) to get to grub menu, or did you install in BIOS/CSM boot mode, then hold shift key to get to grub menu. Is fast boot off in UEFI? What brand/model motherboard? Have you experimented with just booting with internal Intel video? But that also needs a boot parameter: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-SKL-Prelim-Support  Skylake needs this boot parameter:  i915.preliminary_hw_support=1

Comment: Installed in UEFI mode, aaaand the one key I didn't try was esc. I believe I will be able to fix the issue now. Thank you @oldfred!

Answer (score 2):

The solution posted by OP.

If Ubuntu is installed in UEFI mode, the key to access Grub is esc, not shift like usual!